# Which of the following two sentences is grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, indian-english

Which of the following two sentences is grammatically correct? and Why?

> 1. I am giving CAT this year.
> 2. I am taking CAT this year.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: computer-assisted (or -aided) testing.?

Comment: Please add more details to your question. It's unclear what you are asking. What is CAT and what meaning do you need?

Comment: ? You know that these two sentences mean completely different things, yes? So they're both correct, but you just need to add "the" before "CAT".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both grammatically correct. You, as a person, could possibly both take and give the CAT. That is, unless CAT cannot be "given" - in which case it is illogical, but not ungrammatical.

I assume you want to say that you are a student taking the class. Then you would say so.

However, you could also be a teacher giving (teaching) the class. Then you would say so.